# "uninitialized constant" error during migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a newbie in Ruby on Rails and I want to generate a mysql database using migrations.

I tried this command

```
ruby bin/rake db:drop db:create db:migrate --trace
```

but I always get this error:

```
    rake aborted!
    StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

    uninitialized constant CreateOrganisation::Referential
C:/Sites/blog/db/migrate/20120823053740_create_organisation.rb:13:in `up'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:598:in `exec_migration'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:281:in `measure'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with
    _connection'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
    C:in `migrate'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `block in execute_migration_in_transacti
    on'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1039:in `ddl_transaction'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:990:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `block in migrate'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:948:in `each'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:948:in `migrate'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (req
    uired)>'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
    bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
    Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

I tried the commands:

```
rake db:rollback
rake db:reset
rake db:schema:dump  
rake db:schema:load
```

but in vain.

The file that causes the error (I guess) is:

```
class CreateOrganisation < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :organisations do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
    change_table :referentials do |n|
      n.belongs_to :organisation
    end
    change_table :users do |u|
      u.belongs_to :organisation
    end
    Referential.reset_column_information
    User.reset_column_information

    organisation = Organisation.find_or_create_by_name!("Chouette")
    Referential.update_all :organisation_id => organisation.id
    User.update_all :organisation_id => organisation.id
  end

  def down
    drop_table :organisations
  end
end
```

I tried putting `def change..end`  instead of `def up..end/def down..end` but I still get the same error

I can't see what I'm missing here.

Comment: Each migration should do one thing.  For example, the migration called "CreateOrganisation" should just create the `organisations` table and nothing else.  Otherwise you get into a confusing mess when half the code in a migration has worked and the second half has problems.  Put the other things in their own seperate migrations.   I was expecting to see `ReferentialC` instead of `Referential` in your migration, since that seems to be what the error is complaining about.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer but I don't really understand what do you mean. 
could you be more explicit please

Comment: Note that you can step through a migration in the rails console by first typing `irb ActiveRecord::Migration`.  This moves you into the "context" of the class which the migration runs in, so you can do the same code, line by line, which is useful for debugging.

Comment: Ok, you've changed the question :)  Have you created a model file for the Referential class?  ie a file `app/models/referential.rb` which starts with `class Referential < ActiveRecord::Base`?

Comment: Can you post the file name, file location and contents of the class that defines 'Referential'?

Comment: In your 'down' you should also add the reverse for your table updates. I tend to put data migrations into separate migration files, but you could be using a seed file for this.

Comment: @MaxWilliams: The 'ReferentialC' seems to be a concatenation of the constant name and the Windows filename.

Comment: It's generally a *Really Bad Idea* to put references to model code in migrations. Models come and go, they get renamed, but your migrations will stick around for the lifetime of your project. Push anything model-related into a Rake task if necessary. This is also what `db/seeds.rb` is for.

Comment: @Max Williams  yes I was missing a space in the first place :)
Actually I didn't create any model file, The .rb files I have are the ones I retrieved from an application's sources (I need to create a mysql database to do a scaffolding). I read some tutorials, and it wasn't said that I have to create model files.

Comment: Ok, so you're trying to make the models from a scaffold?  The scaffold will make the models and should create migrations to do the corresponding tables in the database.  What you are doing is just trying to do the migrations.  Have you run the scaffold code?  What was it?

Comment: @tadman i think that's a matter of opinion and quite off topic considering the question is so basic.  That point is better suited to a more high level discussion of migrations.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't express myself well
I have to use an application that gives me access just to consultation, but I need to be able tu use POST/PUT/DELETE methods.
so to get around that problem, I want to create the database first, then do a scaffolding to create the corresponding CRUD to my tables.  so for now, all I have done is what I described in my question

Comment: @MaxWilliams It's highly relevant considering removing that model file causes *exactly* this error.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to change the table `referential` and it doesn't exist:

```
change_table :referentials do |n|
  n.belongs_to :organisation
end
```

The error refers to an uninitialized constant ":referentials", which refers to that particular table.

Consider using a generator to create your migrations until you understand how they work; you can always tweak the generated migrations or write your own from scratch later.

### Example

```
rails generate migration CreateFoo name:string amount:integer owner:string:index
```

And that will create

```
class CreateFoo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :amount
      t.string :owner
    end
    add_index :foos, :owner
  end
end
```

### Reference

I suggest you read the [Rails Migration Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html), which should help you understand how to use migrations.

Comment: well it's kind of confusing since even if I have the error bellow, some of the tables are created;  the table "Referential" actually exists but not the table "organisation"

Comment: @user1567118 This is why transactions are key. Unfortunately, MySQL's transactions are not very comprehensive, so you might end up in a state where you'll have to manually back out of of the migration. This is why Max William's comment about migrations only doing one thing is a good practice.